# mortgage calculator formula incorrect

Tags: c++

I'm making a mortgage calculator for my class, the program runs but the answer isn't correct, I think I have the right formula but maybe I'm declaring my variables wrong.

This is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variables
    double rate;
    rate = rate / 1200.0;

    double term;
    term = term * 12;

    double principal;

    double monthlyPayment;
    monthlyPayment = (principal * rate) / (1.0 - pow(rate + 1, -term));


    //Gathering Values
    cout << "Please enter your interest rate." << endl;
    cin >> rate;

    cout << "Please enter your term." << endl;
    cin >> term;

    cout << "please enter your principal" << endl;
    cin >> principal;

    //Formula
    monthlyPayment = principal * rate / (1.0 - pow(rate + 1, -term));

    //Result
    cout << "Your monthly payment is, " << monthlyPayment << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the math you do before the `cin` statements is not being factored in to your calculation. Also, your second formula calculating `monthlyPayment` is missing parentheses in the numerator.

Comment: That worked thank you! still not used to where all my code has to go for it to be factored, your help was very much appreciated!